# Python requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection [Errno 11004]

Tags: python, https, proxy, ssl-certificate, python-requests

So I'm pretty unfamiliar with proxies, but seem to be having an issue regarding them. I see a bunch of similar seeming questions but have been unable to make heads or tails of the responses.

I've written some Python (3.4.3) code to iteratively download a bunch of excel files from an https:// site (I'll call it https_url since its really long) using the requests module

`requests.get(https_url)`

Whenever I run the code on my own work laptop or my computer at home it works fine, but if anyone else at work tries to use it they get the following:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='secure.conservation.ca.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: https_url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000A8EE390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))`

After this I tried using get without verification:

`requests.get(https_url, verify=False)`

Again to no avail. Works on my machines, but on no one else's.

Through reading other answers I have tried two additional things:

1) copy about a dozen different .pem files from places like certifi and reference those as `requests.get(https_url, verify=xyz.pem)` which again works on my machines (work + home), but on no one else's.

2) download my wpad.dat, and reference what I believe to be the proxy server contained in that file: `requests.get(https_url, proxies={'https': proxy_host:proxy_port})` to which I get the following on all machines:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='secure.conservation.ca.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: https_url (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',)))`

I'm at a loss for what to try next. I don't understand what is causing it to work normal on my computers, but none others at work. Surely if there was a proxy issue, it would affect my work laptop too? Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same, and not even `except exceptions.ConnectionError:` appears to catch it. My script is logging: `sh: urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection: No such file or directory` on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the problem for me was to remove the 'https://' from the URL string.
I was trying to use f5 SDK which demanded:

```
x = BigIP('url', user, pass)
```

First I tried:

`x = BigIP(https://example.url.com, user, pass)`

I got a similar error to what you're describing, to solve it I did:

```
x = BigIP(example.url.com, user, pass)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This probably works, because the client uses unencrypted HTTP, and the server allows it. So it is not an acceptable solution in many scenarios.

Comment: i'm with @FlorianWinter on this one, especially since your request appears to also submit user credentials over plain http.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a proxy issue.

In linux, set the following environnement variables:

```
export http_proxy="http://localhost:<proxy_port>"
export https_proxy="http://localhost:<proxy_port>"
```

In windows, I guess you need to go to `Settings -> Network & Internet -> Proxy`